# Are these three molecules optical isomers?

Tags: stereochemistry, isomers

In the structures below (2) vs (3) seem obvious optical isomers to me.

But what about (1)? Is that just a stuctural isomer (e.g. Butane vs Isobutane) or is there a more specific way to describe the relation of (1) vs (2) / (3)?

[image]

Alternative sketch of (2) & (3) based on the comment by @DGS below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: (2) and (3) look like the same molecule to me. I see the wedged and dashed bonds, but those should be up and down, and the way to flip that spot is to switch which is up and which is down.

Comment: @DGS You mean there's an error in the sketch I've used? Or you mean beta vs epi-beta are the same molecule?

Comment: I mean I don't think the wedge and dash is the appropriate way to show stereochemistry from that view. There are two different molecules, I just don't think the image properly represents them both.

Comment: @DGS Thanks! I've uploaded a different set of sketches. Do you feel this set conveys the appropriate sterochemistry?

Comment: Hmm... I don't think any of these are optical isomers of each other now that I look at them again. 2 and 3 both have three chiral centers and only one flips.

Comment: @DGS Ok. So maybe the right way to think about them all is that they are all just structual isomers of each other? Kinda like n-butanol, sec-butanol and ter-butanol?

Comment: Well, (2) and (3) are diastereomers. (1) isn't, but as Lightheart said, it may be a tautomer.

Answer (score 5):

There is no exocyclic methylene in structure 1.  Is it not an optical isomer of 2 and 3.

Likely there is a pericyclic rearrangement between 1 and 2/3 which would formally render them tautomers.

2 and 3 are diastereomers.

Comment: So do you say 2 and 3 are optical isomers?

Comment: No, they are diastereomers.

Comment: Okay. Just wanted to make sure because you hadn't made it real clear. The "*epi*" was a good indication, but the first time I looked at it, I missed the two carbons attached to the bridging carbon.